# Indexing offset diagonal of 4 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

A rather hard question to phrase. I need to index an array such that the following conditions are met for all `a` and `b`:

```
arr[a, b, a, b] = data[b]
```

This can be accomplished by the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = 3
b = 2

arr = np.zeros((a, b, a, b))

data = np.array([10, 20])
rngb = np.arange(b)

for i in range(a):
    arr[i, rngb, i, rngb] += data

print arr
```

The goal here is to remove the python for loop. A trivial answer would be to use `tile` and `repeat` on the index and data arrays, but I believe there is an easier solution that I am missing. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Edit: Another, but likely more costly way of computing `arr`:

```
diag = np.diag(np.ones(a))
arr = np.einsum('ik,jl->ijkl', diag, np.diag(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def meth1(a,b):  # old method
    arr = np.zeros((a,b,a,b))
    data = np.arange(b)+1
    rngb = np.arange(b)
    for i in range(a):
        arr[i, rngb, i, rngb] += data
    return arr

def meth2(a,b):  # revised method
    arr = np.zeros((a, b, a, b))
    data = np.arange(b)+1
    arr.ravel()[::a*b+1] = np.tile(data, a)
    return arr
```

You could test the equality of both with a simple lambda:

```
m = lambda a,b: np.any((meth2(a,b)-meth1(a,b)))
```

Comment: Good answer- this is about 10% faster for large a and b.

Comment: I've done a series of timings as well and the overall speed gain varies wildly depending on the choice of (a,b). But, yes, it's faster. E.g. try (200,2) -> factor 16 and (200, 90) -> factor 1.65, (100, 80) -> factor 1.7 (all on my system of course).